# find the columns with zero elements in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i would like to  know  how  to find all columns  each containing some value? for instance zero? let us suppose  we  have following Dictionary and  corresponding  dataframe

```
import  pandas  as pd
import numpy  as np
revenue_per_country ={"Year":[2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020],
                      "City":["Paris","Moscow","Rome","New York","California","London"],
                       "Revenue":[30000,40000,50000,5000000,0,100000],
                       "GDP":[3400,4500,5600,67000,30400,0]}
revenue_dataframe =pd.DataFrame(revenue_per_country)
print(revenue_dataframe.head(6))
```

given code  returns following dataframe

```
  Year        City  Revenue    GDP
0  2015       Paris    30000   3400
1  2016      Moscow    40000   4500
2  2017        Rome    50000   5600
3  2018    New York  5000000  67000
4  2019  California        0  30400
5  2020      London   100000      0
```

as you see Revenue and GDP  contains one zero elements,what is the effective  function in pandas to find the all columns which contains some value ? please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = revenue_dataframe.loc[:, revenue_dataframe.eq(0).any()]
print (df)
   Revenue    GDP
0    30000   3400
1    40000   4500
2    50000   5600
3  5000000  67000
4        0  30400
5   100000      0
```

**Details**:

First compare all values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for equal:

```
print (revenue_dataframe.eq(0))
    Year   City  Revenue    GDP
0  False  False    False  False
1  False  False    False  False
2  False  False    False  False
3  False  False    False  False
4  False  False     True  False
5  False  False    False   True
```

Then test of at least one match per columns by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (revenue_dataframe.eq(0).any())

Year       False
City       False
Revenue     True
GDP         True
dtype: bool
```

and last filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). But because are filtered columns is necessary add [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with first `:` for all rows and columns by mask.

Comment: revenue_dataframe.eq(0).any() result of this will  be  true/false right

Comment: @datodatuashvili - Give me a sec for explanation

Answer (score 1):

If you Want only Name of columns you can do with:

```
for column in df.columns:
    if any(df[column]==0) :
        print column
```